# Update the row in mySQL, keep the previous entry in column but add the new value next to it

Tags: php, mysql

In my mySQL there is a column `visited` where I save the urls of the pages a visitor visits in my page. The problem is when I use the

```
mysql_query("UPDATE general SET visited = '$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]' WHERE token = '$cookie'");
```

It gets replaced every time but what I want is to have it like page1.php,page2.php,page15.php in the same row.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to concatenate the current value with the new one:

```
// Notice that you should check first if field visited already has
// $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] value in it!
"UPDATE general 
 SET visited = concat(visited,  ',$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]')
 WHERE token = '$cookie'";
```

PS: Edited, Rahul was right, the '+' operator does not throw an error but does not concatenate either, so use the *concat* function and done.

Comment: I think you have to use `concat()` function. `+` operator for concatenation won't work.

Comment: No, at least in mySQL... don't know if it's SQL standard though :-)

Comment: or something happens with the `+`